# ant-design breadcrumbs with ID

Tags: reactjs, react-router, antd

Let's say I have this routing in my react App (`Router` is a `BrowserRouter` here)

```
<Router>
  <PageHeader />
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
      <PrivateRoute
          exact
          path="/project/:projectName"
          component={Project}
      />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

I want to display breadcrumbs in my pageheader. Ant Design docs explain how to do this with fixed paths [here](https://ant.design/components/breadcrumb/#components-breadcrumb-demo-router-4) - by fixed I mean ones like `/` or `/profile`.

What I want to do is for example display a breadcrumb like `Home / FooBar` if user goes to `/projects/FooBar`.

Is there a way to do it? When I use `withRouter` on my `PageHeader`, the location has a pathname of `/project/FooBar`, but for example `match` has `path: "/"`, `url: "/"` and no params (which I expected to contain ID).

So the question is: is there a way to display breadcrumbs like `Home / :projectName`? I can build them with a 3rd party App, but I would want them to go into either ant design's `PageHeader` (as props) or to ant design's `BreadCrumb` component (as children)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using react-router hook [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)?

If your Route is defined as `<Route path="/project/:projectName" />` you should be able to do something like this:

```
const { projectName } = useParams();

<Breadcrumb>
  <Breadcrumb.Item>{`Home / ${projectName}`}</Breadcrumb.Item>
</Breadcrumb>
```

Comment: I actually solved my issue using https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-react-router-breadcrumbs